# Any way to save refactor/rename for later use?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I am in the process of overhauling a C# codebase that involves a lot of renaming of properties and functions.  I have a bunch of scripts that are not part of the solution but call into that code, and I was wondering if there's any way (other than manually writing a series of regex commands or something) to save renamings that are done via either the Visual Studio UI or via Resharper so that they can be run on those other script files that call into the exposed classes.  I'm guessing the answer is no, but it would be a big time saver if there was an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Resharper is only capable of renaming objects inside code and comments, as it's stated [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/10.0/Refactorings__Rename.html?origin=old_help). So I'd better use ctrl+shift+h and regex in Visual Studio (or write a python/perl script for it).

Comment: Well the scripts are still C# code, they are essentially no different than any other code in the solution except they are compiled/executed at runtime.